# input_shapeshape in Keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have question about the input_shape used in Sequential (Keras).

The shape of my training set is: `x_train.shape=(97.167)`

```
def build_model():
  model = models.Sequential()
  model.add(layers.Dense(65, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)))
  model.add(layers.Dense(1))
  model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
  return model
```

1. I don't have the same result if I use `input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],)` et `input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)`??
2. `input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1) = (167,1)`
3. How can I guess the input_shape of model?

Answer (score 0):

In Keras, each type of layer requires a certain number of dimensions in the input :

The `Dense` layers require inputs as `(batch_size, input_size)`
or `(batch_size, optional,...,optional, input_size)`.
Here the input_size is equal to the number of features in your data. In your case it is 167. Hence the `input_shape = (None,167,)`.

The `2D convolutional` layers need inputs as:

- if using channels_last:     `(batch_size, imageside1, imageside2, channels)`
- if using channels_first:
  `(batch_size, channels, imageside1, imageside2)`

The `1D convolutions` and `recurrent layers` use `(batch_size, sequence_length, features)`.

Using `input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1) = (167,1)`, adds one more dimension to the data and hence both the results are different.